# Generating Laravel projects from a single installation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to know how to generate new Laravel projects from a single Laravel installation. For instance in Symfony, you can issue a command and a new Symfony project will be created for you to develop your application. You don't need to install multiple copies of Symfony all the time.

This means that you can generate multiple projects from the same Symfony installation. Is it possible to that in Laravel?

I have Laravel version 4 installed on my computer and I would like to create multiple projects to build multiple applications.

Under normal circumstances what I do is to install a new copy of Laravel but I think maybe there must be a better way to generate projects inside a single Laravel installation.

Comment: laracasts are the best source for begginers. One of episodes are about intalation

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need, you can create a new laravel project/folder/installation with a single line command using composer

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/1